# How do I put the navbar on top of all the text?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I got this problem here that when I open the navbar it won't come on top, why isn't the navbar on top of all the text/button? How can I put it on top? Thank you.

[image: Problem]

```
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/turbo0/pen/NWBMNQr)
```

Comment: Applying a negative z-index to your content fixed it for me.

Comment: Thank you, z-index and position relative for the text fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a **z-index** property to the navbar element and give it a value greater than the **z-index** of the elements underneath. This will ensure that the navbar is on top of the other elements.

Answer (score 0):

use z index property inside your main div component or make your nav at absolute position with 100% width

Answer (score 0):

Give it a z-index greater than the others

```
nav { 
z-index: 5 
}
```

doesn't really have to be 5, most likely 2 would do the job assuming you haven't done anything weird